# how a variable referencing an array element also affect another array created from the first array?

Tags: php, arrays, reference

```
$array1=array(1,2);
$x=&$array1[1];
$array2=$array1;
$array2[1]=22;
print_r($array1);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 22
)
```

`$array2` just copied the value from `$array1` to new address, it's not referencing to `$array1`, so changing `$array2[1]` shouldn't change `$array1`. if I delete the 2nd line where `$x` refer to `$array1[1]` then it behaves normally.
`$array2[1]` and `$x` not refer to the same address. so how `$x` effecting the `$array2[1]` ?

Answer (score 0):

according to php.net document :

> however, that references inside arrays are potentially dangerous. Doing a normal (not by reference) assignment with a reference on the right side does not turn the left side into a reference, but references inside arrays are preserved in these normal assignments. This also applies to function calls where the array is passed by value
>
> In other words, the reference behavior of arrays is defined in an element-by-element basis; the reference behavior of individual elements is dissociated from the reference status of the array container.

see this php.net document :

[Link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

Doing a normal (not by reference) assignment with a reference on the right side does not turn the left side into a reference, but references inside arrays are preserved in these normal assignments.
See the Link:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1=array(1,2);
```

After this line zval of 2nd element in $array1 seems like this: (is_ref => 0, refcount => 1, ...)

```
$x=&$array1[1];
```

This line set is_ref field in zval into 1 (true) and refcount into 2 (1+1)

```
$array2=$array1;
```

This line set refcount in zval into 3 (2+1), is_ref is still 1 (true)

```
$array2[1]=22;
```

At this line interpretator saw is_ref=1 and think, what there is only *references* on this zval (and don't do copy-on-write).